# Can't build against functions in system library

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I'm going crazy here.

Basically, I'm trying to access some functions in a shared library located in system/lib/ on the android platform, using the NDK.

The library I'm trying to make use of is libsonivox.so.  My main goal is to use it from a NativeActivity.  I understand this can complicate things because I would need to load this library (statically) before I load my own library which depends on it.  Therefore I am trying to get it to work through a regular Activity and JNI.

In the Activity I load the libraries like so:

```
static {
  System.loadLibrary("sonivox");
  System.loadLibrary("native-audio-jni");
}
```

The "native-audio-jni" library is from the NDK samples, but I am modifying it in a rudimentary attempt to access the sonivox functions.

Without any calls to libsonivox from libnative-audio-jni, everything compiles fine.
This line from the LogCat output gives me hope:

```
  04-26 15:01:14.973: D/dalvikvm(691): No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libsonivox.so   
  0x412a1100, skipping init
```

So the library is loaded.

Then I add this function to native-audio-jni.c:

```
void Java_jay_enn_eye_JNImidiActivity_createMidi(JNIEnv* env,
        jclass clazz)
{
  pLibConfig = EAS_Config();
}
```

pLibConfig is declared like this:

```
static const S_EAS_LIB_CONFIG* pLibConfig = NULL;
```

When that is declared, without the addition of the above function, it compiles fine.  So at least the header files are... there.

When I plop that function into the code, this is the output of ndk-build:

```
  Compile thumb  : native-audio-jni <= native-audio-jni.c
  SharedLibrary  : libnative-audio-jni.so
  ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/native-audio-jni/native-audio-jni.o: In function
  `Java_jay_enn_eye_JNImidiActivity_createMidi':
  /home/anthony/Documents/eclipse/JNImidi/jni/native-audio-jni.c:202: undefined   
  reference
  to `EAS_Config'
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libnative-audio-jni.so] Error 1
```

I'm not sure if libnative-audio-jni just can't access libsonivox, or if I need to dlsym() or sym() link the sonivox functions to use them.  I haven't been able to try either of those since the library is found in system/lib/ and not provided by me, so I don't have a full path to provide to do that.

Another option I am considering is grabbing libsonivox.so, copying it into a directory in the project, and changing the Android.mk so that it includes the lib as a prebuilt shared library.  I was thinking maybe the library needs to be included at compile time.

**EDIT:**  Here's the Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := native-audio-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native-audio-jni.c
# for native audio
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -lOpenSLES
# for logging
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -llog
# for native asset manager
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -landroid

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

This must be where something isn't right.  I'd think the sonivox library **would** need to be present when compiling everything.  However, the library won't load no matter what changes I make to this file, which have mainly involved trying to include it as a PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY or PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY.  Also, the OpenSL stuff works perfectly fine.  I wish sonivox would work if I were to just include it as -lsonivox, but no.

Comment: Sorry my question is so wordy!  Just trying to give all the details.  I'm dying to figure this out.

Comment: Show your Android.mk makefile.

Comment: This is a build error, not a runtime one.  You need to get that -lsonivox working or come up with something having the same effect.  Incidentally, is that even a stable API you are supposed to use?  If it's not, realize you are in tricky territory.

Comment: I just added the Android.mk to my original post.

Comment: Thanks Chris!  I'll try different variations of throwing -lsonivox into the .mk. I can't say for sure about the stability of the API, but I know that the exact same library has been included in every Android version since 1.5.  Also JetPlayer relies on this library and I think that's considered a stable API, so sonivox would have to be stable by proxy.

Comment: @AnthonyS, no, there is no such thing as "stable by proxy".  Indeed, quite the opposite.  The point is that Google (or even some downstream vendor) are free to change the interaction between the private libraries, as long as the API blessed for public use remains the same.  Directly invoking non-public libraries is warned against specifically for that reason.  And they don't go out of their way to provide instructions for how to link what they don't recommend using. (Note: I am not declaring libsonivox to be non-public, I am merely speculating complications if that is the case)

Comment: Though the fact that there is no libsonivox.a beside the libc.a and similar in *my* installation of the NDK strongly hints that it is indeed non-stable.  As a guess, to *take your chances* using the installed version, you'd need to compile a stub version, play with allow-undefined flags, or programmatically resolve the functions by talking to the runtime linker within your program.  **Danger Will Robinson**

Comment: It's interesting that libsonivox.a isn't included in the NDK, as you pointed out.  Why would the library be included on the devices themselves though?  I was thinking there could be a different version of it for different phones/devices, but with the same functionality available to whatever app needs it.  That would make me nervous if that's the case though, because I could definitely see some unforeseen problems stemming from that.  With all that in mind, maybe it would be best to include my own copy of that library?  That way I could make sure it doesn't change.

Comment: The point of a public API is that it's something you can rely on while the underlying interfaces private to the implementation can change to reflect the needs of the hardware or whims of the implementor.  Including your own version would only help if the library does not in turn depend on other private APIs or directly on device dependent (hardware) details.

Comment: You are insanely helpful, Chris.  My naivety just can't stop emerging, though.  I know that the sonivox library has no direct access to the hardware layer, it merely sits on top of AudioFlinger and throws bytes at it.  The sonivox provided header files, optimistically titled "public interface header", do not include any foreign(?) types.  If there was some way to verify the library doesn't rely on private APIs, then I personally would be comfortable using the library.  Maybe not for taking a trip to the ISS, but certainly for making beep sounds in my bedroom.

Comment: AudioFlinger doesn't even require direct access actually, the situation is more like sonivox > openSL > AudioFlinger > hardware.  I've seen other devs successfully do sonivox > AudioTrack (java) > AudioFlinger etc.  I'm picturing sonivox as a self-contained music box that does nothing but output sound to any available sink (openSL's bufferQueue), with occasional interaction from higher up.

Comment: I grepped my libsonivox.so and didn't seem to find any non-public .so's mentioned.  Building your own copy against the NDK and looking for undefined reference errors would be a decent first attempt to check.  Must say I'm not really familiar with this library, precisely what it does, who wrote it, licensing etc.  If you want to take chances in the short term you can probably get a .a file out of a system build to satisfy the build linker or use the allow undefined flag, but including your own library with the app (if possible/permitted) would seem to give you most immunity to changes.

Comment: more generic howto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115827/how-to-link-libmedia-so-in-android-system-library-from-android-mk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got carried away with other things, but I figured out the answer to this recently...
libsonivox.so can be loaded dynamically.  You need to copy the .so from your android device and place it in $NDK-ROOT/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/lib, "android-14" can be whatever version instead.
That way it can be compiled against, and when the app is running on a device it uses the library on that device.

Comment: Yes, and add `-lsonyvox` to `LOCAL_LDLIBS`