# Build OpenSSL for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, openssl

I try to build OpenSSL for arm Android as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18577811). But when I build OpenSSL with "shared" flag, it produces 4 files: libcrypto.so.1.0.0, libssl.so.1.0.0 and 2 symbolic links: libcrypto.so and libssl.so

In Android.mk file I link these libraries to project:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := openssl-ssl
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/libssl.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := openssl-crypto
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/libcrypto.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But when I try to run my application java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError occurs with message "Could not load library libssl.so.1.0.0..."

I tryed to delete links and rename libssl.so.1.0.0 and libcrypto.so.1.0.0 to libssl.so and libcrypto.so respectively but it doesn't help.

How can I use OpenSSL in my project?

Comment: Why? SSL is already supported.

Comment: Yes, Android partially supports OpenSSL but libraries under /system/lib are inaccessible for developers.

Comment: Thousands of developers use the `/system/lib` libraries that are not included in NDK. Very few problems have been encountered. OTOH, `/system/lib/libssl.so` is not the latest version, and may have some features missing.

Comment: How can I use these libraries from NDK?

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13116965/192373

Comment: You need a version-less `libcrypto.so`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/33869277/4735903.

Answer (score 2):

To be on the safe side, use a static build of openssl. Otherwise you will probably find that the system one is loaded instead of your custom one (`System.loadLibrary()` looks in `/system/lib` first). Or go into openssl make file and change its **soname** to something unique.

Comment: I need to build "own" OpenSSl version with custom engine so I can't use /system/lib/libssl.so. But your advice is very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was:
Edit the openssl Makefile.shared and replace

```
-soname=$$SHLIB$$SHLIB_SOVER$$SHLIB_SUFFIX
```

with

```
-soname=$$SHLIB
```

That way the library internal name is changed do libcrypto.so and libssl.so instead of libcrypto.so.1.0.0

Clean and recompile openssl and your app.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to delete the links and rename the files. Just keep them in the same folder which is referenced in the Android.mk file.(in your case, the four files should all be in the lib folder)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build the static version of the libraries.  libcrypto.a and libssl.a   It is not possible to load the custom libcrypto.so and libssl.so because the Android Zygote process has already loaded its own version of these shared libraries.

OpenSSL-1.0.2k configurations that I am currently using on Android:

ARM: `./Configure android no-shared no-hw no-dso no-krb5 no-zlib --openssldir=/home/jeff/openssl/$ANDROID_API`

ARM-v7a: `./Configure android-armv7 no-shared no-hw no-dso no-krb5 no-zlib --openssldir=/home/jeff/openssl/$ANDROID_API`

x86: `./Configure android-x86 no-shared no-hw no-dso no-krb5 no-zlib --openssldir=/home/jeff/openssl/$ANDROID_API`