# UnsatisfiedLinkError: libcrypto.so.1.0.0 not found

Tags: android-ndk, openssl

I am using android ndk in eclipse. I got my project compiled but am facing errors at run time. I have the `libcrytpoNative.so` and `libsslNative.so` files but I am getting this error about `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` not found error. How should I fix this?

This is the output of `ndk-build V=1`

```
    Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-21 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 14 in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
    rm -f ./libs/arm64-v8a/lib*.so ./libs/armeabi/lib*.so ./libs/armeabi-v7a/lib*.so ./libs/armeabi-v7a-hard/lib*.so ./libs/mips/lib*.so ./libs/mips64/lib*.so ./libs/x86/lib*.so ./libs/x86_64/lib*.so
    rm -f ./libs/arm64-v8a/gdbserver ./libs/armeabi/gdbserver ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver ./libs/armeabi-v7a-hard/gdbserver ./libs/mips/gdbserver ./libs/mips64/gdbserver ./libs/x86/gdbserver ./libs/x86_64/gdbserver
    rm -f ./libs/arm64-v8a/gdb.setup ./libs/armeabi/gdb.setup ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup ./libs/armeabi-v7a-hard/gdb.setup ./libs/mips/gdb.setup ./libs/mips64/gdb.setup ./libs/x86/gdb.setup ./libs/x86_64/gdb.setup
    [armeabi-v7a] Install        : libcpabe.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libcpabe.so
    install -p ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libcpabe.so ./libs/armeabi-v7a/libcpabe.so
    /home/yogi/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip --strip-unneeded  ./libs/armeabi-v7a/libcpabe.so
    [armeabi-v7a] Install        : libcryptoNative.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libcryptoNative.so
    install -p ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libcryptoNative.so ./libs/armeabi-v7a/libcryptoNative.so
    /home/yogi/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip --strip-unneeded  ./libs/armeabi-v7a/libcryptoNative.so
    [armeabi-v7a] Install        : libglib.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libglib.so
    install -p ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libglib.so ./libs/armeabi-v7a/libglib.so
    /home/yogi/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip --strip-unneeded  ./libs/armeabi-v7a/libglib.so
    [armeabi-v7a] Install        : libgmp.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libgmp.so
    install -p ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libgmp.so ./libs/armeabi-v7a/libgmp.so
    /home/yogi/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip --strip-unneeded  ./libs/armeabi-v7a/libgmp.so
    [armeabi-v7a] Install        : libpbc.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libpbc.so
    install -p ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libpbc.so ./libs/armeabi-v7a/libpbc.so
    /home/yogi/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip --strip-unneeded  ./libs/armeabi-v7a/libpbc.so
    [armeabi-v7a] Install        : libsslNative.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libsslNative.so
    install -p ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libsslNative.so ./libs/armeabi-v7a/libsslNative.so
    /home/yogi/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip --strip-unneeded  ./libs/armeabi-v7a/libsslNative.so
```

This is the MainActivity.java that loads libs:

package com.example.myproject;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("gmp");             
//        System.loadLibrary("ssl");
//        System.loadLibrary("crypto");
        System.loadLibrary("glib");
        System.loadLibrary("pbc"); 
        System.loadLibrary("sslNative");
        System.loadLibrary("cryptoNative");
        System.loadLibrary("cpabe");          
    }

    //System.loadLibrary("ssl_static");


    public static native void InitMainActivityjni();
    public native String cpabeNative();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView  tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(cpabeNative());
        setContentView(tv);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Also see [Changing OpenSSL library in Android app for HttpClient](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28392326/608639). It discusses Zygote and problems with supplying your own copies of `libcrytpo.so` and `libssl.so`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Android does not like versioned library files, and changing the file name of the .so lib alone will not do in this case. A nice trick you can do to see the actual name assigned to the library is by running `readelf` (if your .so file is in elf format, if not, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732/how-do-i-list-the-symbols-in-a-so-file) post for other options).

Once you run this, you will need to look for items appearing under `DEPEND` & `SONAME`. If you see the versioned .so.1.0.0 name, then keep on reading, salvation is near :)

Now, you basically have two choices - either recompile your libcrypto.so & libssl.so again, this time adding the appropriate flags preventing it from appending the version suffix, or edit the libs to remove the version suffix. I will show how to to do the 2nd option.

Ensure you have the `rpl` command line tool installed. If it isnt, run:

```
brew install rpl
```

You might need to run this with `sudo`.

Once this tool is installed, you will need to use it to edit the symbols in both the ssl & crypto libraries like so:

```
rpl -R -e .so.1.0.0 "_1_0_0.so" /path/to/libssl.so
rpl -R -e .so.1.0.0 "_1_0_0.so" /path/to/libcrypto.so
```

Almost done!

Run the `readelf` tool again to make sure the symbols have been properly changed. The only thing left to do now is to change the actual file names to `libssl_1_0_0.so` & `libcrypto_1_0_0.so`, and when loading the library, make sure to use the adjusted file names:

```
System.loadLibrary("ssl_1_0_0");
System.loadLibrary("crypto_1_0_0");
```

Things should work now. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: "Now, you basically have two choices - either recompile your libcrypto.so & libssl.so again, this time adding the appropriate flags preventing it from appending the version suffix,"
Do you know how to do this? I haven't been able to figure this out openssl 1.1.1. I can' t find anything in the documentation for it either.

Comment: @MattWolfe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24204366/how-to-build-openssl-as-unversioned-shared-lib-for-android