# How can i solve libmedia.so issue in htc?

Tags: android, htc-android

I got crash from HTC One (M8) (htc_m8) when my app get start.
I can not find any related issue in my app. It's may be device related issue But other app running normally.
Please help me to find that it's device specific or app specific.

Here is crash from google developer account:

---

**Build fingerprint:**

```
'htc/htc_europe/htc_m8:5.0.1/LRX22C/448934.10:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm'
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
r0 00000000 r1 00000000 r2 8f92f988 r3 00000b40
r4 bd5ef848 r5 0000000c r6 0000000c r7 00000001
r8 8f92f984 r9 ffffffff sl 00000005 fp b593caf0
ip 96771000 sp 8f92f928 lr b6f111d9 pc b58f0f58 cpsr 60070030
```

**backtrace:**

```
#00 pc 00053f58 /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::AudioRecord::openRecord_l(unsigned int)+379)
#01 pc 000549fd /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::AudioRecord::restoreRecord_l(char const*)+136)
#02 pc 00054be9 /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::AudioRecord::obtainBuffer(android::AudioRecord::Buffer*, timespec const*, timespec*, unsigned int*)+92)
#03 pc 00054e4d /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::AudioRecord::read(void*, unsigned int)+156)
#04 pc 00097075 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#05 pc 00272667 /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libmedia.so` are not part of the public API. So you can not rely on them. These libraries are present on all devices, but they are different. So I think the problem is more device specific.

There is a similar problem on: [How to link libmedia.so in android system library from android.mk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115827/how-to-link-libmedia-so-in-android-system-library-from-android-mk)
Maybe the link can help you.

Comment: @VijayVala -- You are welcome. If I could help you, mark this as accepted. So the community can see this issue was resolved.